# Fastest way to do Maximum Inner Product Search?

Tags: information-retrieval, search

There have lots of $d-$dimension vectors, they combine a set $X$. We use an input query $q$. We need to find the $p$, which has the maximum inner product from the set $X$.

$$
    p = \arg \max_{x \in X} x^T \ q
$$

```py
import torch
import time

def main():

    device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

    matrix_size = 800000000
    dim_size = 768
    batch_size = 100000  # Adjust the batch size based on available memory

    # create a query vector using torch
    query = torch.randn(1, dim_size, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)

    print("Query vector:", query)

    # start timing
    start = time.time()

    for i in range(0, matrix_size, batch_size):
        # create a batch of the matrix
        matrix_batch = torch.randn(batch_size, dim_size, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
        
        # calculate the inner product for the batch
        result_batch = torch.matmul(matrix_batch, query.T)
        
        # torch topk, k = 10 for the batch
        values_batch, indices_batch = torch.topk(result_batch.squeeze(), k=10)

        # process the top-k results as needed
        print("Top values in batch:", values_batch)
        print("Indices in batch:", indices_batch)

    # end timing
    end = time.time()
    print("Time elapsed: ", end - start)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Similar with nearest neighbor question, changing the definition to find a $p$, which makes the distance between $q$ to become closer.

Here the distance set as Euclidean distance.

$$
p = \arg \min_{x \in X} \| q - x \|^2 = (\| x \|^2 - 2q^T x)
$$

**If the vector module in $X$ are all the same, then the two problems are actually equivalent.**

However, in many practical scenarios, such as BERT-encoded sentence vectors, various Embeddings in recommendation systems, etc., this constraint is not satisfied.

##### Locality-sensitive hashing

- [Reformer: The Efficient Transformer](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.04451.pdf)

> LSH seems to be a big step forward compared to the naive algorithm. **But don’t be too happy. To achieve the effect of $O(d \log N)$ ($N$ is the # documents), you must obey that strong assumption. It is often unrealistic for points to be distributed evenly in space.** In addition to this, an LSH can only be suitable for certain distance measures. For MIPS, no LSH that meets the requirements can be found.

##### Asymmetric LSH(ALSH)

- [Asymmetric LSH (ALSH) for Sublinear Time Maximum Inner Product Search (MIPS)](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper_files/paper/2014/file/310ce61c90f3a46e340ee8257bc70e93-Paper.pdf)

Can anyone suggest an algorithm? Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using a vector database like [faiss](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss)? They are meant to address the problem you described. However, as you use PyTorch in your code, I am afraid that you may have other requirements that didn't mention explicitly in your question.

Comment: @noe We just want to search relative document based on the query. I think faiss may help us. Thanks.

Comment: Great! I added an answer with more information on the matter so that the question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is a fast way of vector-search documents, then a vector database may fit your needs.

Some popular ones include [faiss](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss) and [pinecone](https://www.pinecone.io/).

If you already have a PostgreSQL database, you may also consider using the [pgvector extension](https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector).